# Import a NPAPI DLL in a C++ application

Tags: c++, dll, invoke, npapi

I have to import a NPAPI DLL in a C++ application for my project.
I follow the excellent tutorial : http://colonelpanic.net/2009/03/building-a-firefox-plugin-part-one/

However I have some trouble to access to the methods of the dll. (Note: in a browser the dll is completly functional). After calling the main functions : NP_GetEntryPoints and NP_Initialize and retrieving the ScriptableNPObject, the invocation of the methods return no value with no error. The property or method names are the same used in javascript in the browser (functional case).

For information, the property and method names and the mime-type have been replaced in this sample.

Anyone has an idea to invoke the methods of the dll by simulating what the browser does?

Here is a part of the main program:

```
if (hDLL == 0)
{
    std::cout << "DLL failed to load!" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "DLL loaded!" << std::endl;

    //WRAP NP_GETENTRYPOINTS FUNCTION:
    _GetEntryPointsFunc = (GetEntryPointsFunc)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "NP_GetEntryPoints");
    if (_GetEntryPointsFunc)
    {
        std::cout << "Get NP_GetEntryPoints Function!" << std::endl;
        status = _GetEntryPointsFunc(pFuncs);

    }

    //WRAP NP_INITIALIZE FUNCTION:
    _InitializeFunc = (InitializeFunc)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "NP_Initialize");
    if (_InitializeFunc)
    {   
        std::cout << "Get NP_Initialize Function!" << std::endl;
        status = _InitializeFunc(&sBrowserFuncs);
    }


    int32_t       mode = NP_EMBED; 
    int32_t       argc = 7;
    static const char mimetype[] = "application/x-mime_type_of_my_plugin";

    char * argn[] = {"param1", "param2", "param3", "param4", "param5", "param6", "param7"};
    char * argv[] = { "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5", "value6", "value7" };



    NPObject np_object;
    uint16_t size;
    char* descritpionString;
    char* nameString;

  instance = &(plugin_instance.mNPP);
    status = pFuncs->newp((char*)mimetype, instance, (uint16_t)mode, argc, argn, argv, &saved);
    status = pFuncs->version; //OK  
    status = pFuncs->getvalue(instance,NPPVpluginDescriptionString,&descritpionString); //OK
    status = pFuncs->getvalue(instance,NPPVpluginNameString,&nameString); //OK

    status = pFuncs->getvalue(instance,NPPVpluginScriptableNPObject,&np_object); //ISSUE STARTS HERE

    std::cin.get();

}
```

Here is my create_object function called after getting the scriptable NPObject with the getvalue function:

```
NPObject* _createobject(NPP npp, NPClass* aClass)
{

if (!npp) {
    return nullptr;
}

if (!aClass) {
    return nullptr;
}

NPObject *npobj;

if (aClass->allocate) {
    npobj = aClass->allocate(npp, aClass);
} else {
    npobj = (NPObject *)malloc(sizeof(NPObject));
}

if (npobj) {
    npobj->_class = aClass;
    npobj->referenceCount = 1;

    //TEST:
            NPError status;
    NPString url;
    NPVariant result;
    NPVariant variant;
    NPIdentifier property = "existing_property";
    NPIdentifier *arrayId;
    uint32_t count = 2;

    const char *str = "https://test_url.com";
    url.UTF8Characters = str;//;
    url.UTF8Length = 20;

    variant.type = NPVariantType_String;
    variant.value.stringValue = url;
    NPVariant args[] = { variant };

    status = 1; //GENERIC ERROR VALUE
    status = npobj->_class->structVersion; //OK
    status = npobj->_class->hasMethod(npobj,L"existing_set_function"); //STATUS OK
    status = npobj->_class->enumerate(npobj, &arrayId, &count); //Privileged instruction ERROR
    status = npobj->_class->hasProperty(npobj, property); //STATUS OK
    status = npobj->_class->getProperty(npobj, property, &result); //STATUS OK BUT NO RESULT
    status = npobj->_class->invoke(npobj,L"existing_set_function",args,1,&result); //STATUS OK
    status = npobj->_class->invoke(npobj,L"existing_get_function",args,0,&result); //STATUS OK BUT NO RESULT
    status = npobj->_class->invokeDefault(npobj,args,0,&result); //STATUS OK BUT NO RESULT
    //END TEST
}
return npobj;
}
```

Finally, here is the plugin_instance methods to declare ndata and pdata:

```
nsNPAPIPluginInstance::nsNPAPIPluginInstance()
{
  mNPP.pdata = NULL;
  mNPP.ndata = this;
}

nsNPAPIPluginInstance::~nsNPAPIPluginInstance()
{

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While it is unclear what "no result" means, a privileged instruction error suggests the function pointer is off.

I'd start with:

- Checking that `structVersion >= NP_CLASS_STRUCT_VERSION_ENUM` (otherwise `NPClass::enumerate` [is not available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/NPClass#Fields))
- Using the proper [npapi-sdk headers](http://code.google.com/p/npapi-sdk/) - your function pointer type names suggest you are not doing that
- Using a simple test plugin to see what happens on the plugin side
- Take care that the `NPIdentifier`s match up between your host application and the plugin, i.e. use a common string->NPIdentifier mapping for the host code and `NPN_GetStringIdentifier()` - as posted this can't work
- Don't test the `NPObject` right in the creation function - the plugin may set things up to work properly only after `NPN_CreateObject()` returned

Comment: I hadn't tested the NP_CLASS_STRUCT_VERSION_ENUM  and effectively the enumerate function is not available, thank you. I modified the use of NPIdentifiers and tested the program on a simple test plugin. It works fine: the simple plugin calls the NPN_utf8fromidentifier and the method is invoked. But it dosen't work with the plugin to import. I also tested the NPObject after NPN_CreateObject() returned but no effect: the methods aren't invoked and no call is done to any API functions. Is it possible that the plugin uses some browser ressources outside of API functions?

Comment: What do you mean with "the methods aren't invoked", does it return an error? Have you tested your `NPIdentifier` usage with your test plugin doing something like `if (nameArg == NPN_GetStringIdentifier("methodName") ...`? It's always possible that a plugin does weird things or is buggy, but it might me be a much simpler issue.

Comment: I mean with "the method aren't invoke" that the invoke function returns false. Yes I tested the NPIdentifier usage in the test plugin and it works fine. I declare my NPidentifiers like that : NPIdentifier method = "method_name";  The test plugin calls as expected the NPN_utf8fromidentifier function to do the conversion but the other plugin does nothing. Yes, I'm sure it is a simpler issue.

Comment: Is it possible to use another object that the scriptableNPObject to invoke functions?

Comment: That `NPIdentifier` usage is probably your issue - when the plugin calls `NPN_GetStringIdentifier("foo")`, it has to match your identifier for `"foo"`. In C/C++ strings are not interned, so you can't just use their pointer values - you need to use some mapping string↔`NPIdentifier` that does not depend on the strings pointer value.

Comment: The value `NPPVpluginScriptableNPObject` is the plugins "main" scriptable object - it can hand you other scriptable objects from there etc., but all the scripting starts from that one object.

Comment: If it helps, a simple check your `NPIdentifier` implementation wont pass: `NPN_GetStringIdentifier(_strdup("method_name"))==yourMethodIdentifier`.

Comment: There is something weird. The plugin doesn't call NPN_GetStringIdentifier or utf8fromidentifier as does the Flash dll or the simple dll after a function invocation. Is it normal?

Comment: There are 4 functions relevant to string identifiers: `NPN_GetStringIdentifier`, `NPN_GetStringIdentifiers`, `NPN_UTF8FromIdentifier`, `NPN_IdentifierIsString`. The plugin has to call one of the first three (and optionally also the last one) to handle things like method calls - otherwise something else is wrong. Have you checked all four?

Comment: Yes I checked all four, the plugin calls no function. Is it possible that my NPN functions are badly declared (but the createobject function is however well invoked by the plugin...)?

Comment: Hm, if they are in the function table similar to `NPN_CreateObject` i suppose there is something else that leads to the plugin not calling them. Are you testing the method call in a proper place now? E.g. right after your `getvalue(NPPVpluginScriptableNPObject)` call should work. Otherwise it's getting hard to do remote guesses at what could be wrong at this point. I could take a look if anything stands out in updated sample code... or you could check into the communication between the plugin & a browser to see if they do something that's missing with your app.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems that the plugin can be used without a browser (according designers).That's why no call is done to the 4 functions relevant the string identifiers. I have to find antoher way ;). Thanks again

Comment: Sure. I wonder though how the plugin notices that it isn't loaded in a browser. If you knew you could fake that part.